# read wsdl file using php

Tags: php, soap

How we can read a wsdl file in php?
http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdl
How we can make a client of this wsdl file?
If any one have any idea about this. Please help me..

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the [`SoapClient`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) class in PHP.

You start off with something like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx?wsdl");
$result = $client->SomeMethod();
```

Where `SomeMethod` is a function defined within the WSDL file.

Comment: how can we print the result? can you please give me an example or demo for this.

Comment: How to pass the access token to the  method